# Ruby shell command with double quotes

Tags: ruby, shell

I want to pass JSON-formatted string as script argument inside backtick, e.g.:

```
stats = "[[\"25/01/2017 03:15 PST\",
           \"26/01/2017 03:15 PST\",
           \"27/01/2017 03:15 PST\",
           \"28/01/2017 03:15 PST\"]]"

`my_executable_script.js "#{stats}"`
```

And get a stdout value (it's important). The problem is that JSON argument should be escaped with double quotes, like:

```
my_executable_script.js "[[\"25/01/2017 03:15 PST....."
```

but `my_executable_script.js [[\"25/01/2017 03:15 PST.....]]` is executed instead (without `""`), which is wrong. I tried different ways of escaping, no success.

I cannot use `system()` method because I need the result of the script executing.

Comment: `%Q{}`? Also, within the string that should not be interpolated, single quotes rule.

Comment: Could you possibly use JSON.stringify?

Comment: @mudasobwa, The question is not about how to build a string with double quotes inside, it's mostly about how to pass this string inside backticks (``).

Comment: @theTinMan, 1. I don't need thousands of files in my system. 2. It's faster, no need to write/read/delete a file each time, it's senseless. 3.Your suggestion  actually is more complicate: we need to create a file with the unique name each time because of multithreading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`Shellwords.escape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-escape):

```
>> require 'shellwords'
>> puts %x|echo #{Shellwords.escape(stats)}|

[["25/01/2017 03:15 PST",
  "26/01/2017 03:15 PST",
  "27/01/2017 03:15 PST",
  "28/01/2017 03:15 PST"]]
```

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the `Shellwords` module. There's an informative article about it [here](https://endofline.wordpress.com/2010/12/14/ruby-standard-library-shellwords/).